# GitHub notifications showing "unread"

Tags: github

For a while now my GitHub notifications page has been showing "1 unread" notification, even though all my notifications are "read". Nothing is listed when clicking the "unread" tab (or the "all" tab for that matter).

How can I clear this? It's quite annoying!

[image: Unread?]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So - I found a way to clear this (with a bit of help from this thread: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/6874)

Here's the process I used:

- Goto the `Done` tab
- Click `select all` then click `move to inbox`
- Goto the `Inbox`
- Click `select all` then `mark as unread`
- Click the link that says `select all xxx messages`
- Click `Done`

Hopefully this should clear the ghost "unread" message!

Comment: > Click Done

For me marking them as "Read" also worked, without moving to "Done"